# Como obter a última localização do dispositivo

Tags: android, gps

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de obter a ultima localização do **GPS**, antes de eu rodar a opção para executar o obtenção da posição atual.

```
public class Localization{

 private GetGPSResponse delegate = null;

 public void setDelegate(GetGPSResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
 }


 //Método que faz a leitura de fato dos valores recebidos do GPS
 public void startGPS(Object local, final Context context){
    final LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager) local ;
    LocationListener lListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location locat) {
            if( locat != null ) {
                delegate.getGPSResponse(locat);
                lManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
    };
    lManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, lListener, null);
 }

 interface GetGPSResponse{
    void getGPSResponse(Location location);
 }
}
```

Comment: Você poderia salvar a variável `Location locat` para uma variável na classe. Tipo: `public class Localization{ private Localtion lastLocat`.

Answer (score 2):

O objeto **LocationManager** possui o método [`getLastKnownLocation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29) que você pode utilizar para este caso, e se houver sucesso, é possível também obter qual foi a data desta última localização, assim você garante que não foi obtido uma localização muito antiga. É o que costumo fazer.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
boolean isSignificantlyNewer = false;

Location lastKnownLocation = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    long timeDelta = currentDate.getTime() - lastKnownLocation.getTime();
    isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta < 120000;
}

if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
    // A última localização foi obtida a menos de 2 minutos
} else {
    // Não possui última localização ou ela tem mais de 2 minutos
    lManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, lListener, null);
}
```